# reference x's column in R's apply function

Tags: r

I have a df like this:

```
a <- c(4,5,3,5,1)
b <- c(8,9,7,3,5)
c <- c(6,7,5,4,3)
df <- data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))
```

I want a new df, df2, containing the difference between the values in each cell in rows a and b and the value in row c in their respective columns.

df2 would look like this:

```
a <- c(-2,-2,-2,1,-2)
b <- c(2,2,2,-1,2)
df2 <- data.frame(rbind(a,b))
```

Here is where I'm getting stuck:

```
df2 <- data.frame(apply(df,c(1,2),function(x) x - df[nrow(df),the col index of x]))
```

How do I reference the column index of x? Is there something like JavaScript's `this`?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but why not just transpose, then use standard data frame syntax?

Comment: In fact, why even transpose? What's wrong with `df - df["c", , drop = TRUE]` and then deleting row `"c"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this easily by replicating the 3rd row to make the lengths equal before subtracting with the first two rows

```
out <- df[c("a", "b"),] - df["c",][col(df[c("a", "b"),])]    
identical(df2, out)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or explicitly using `rep`

```
df[c("a", "b"),] - rep(unlist(df["c",]), each = 2)
```

Comment: The sample data that I provided is much smaller than the actual df I'm working with. My real df has 30 rows, and I'd like to avoid typing in the name of each row within `c()`.

Comment: @orangeman51  You don't need to type the rows.  It is just that you specifically mentione the names, I used it.  Supposet you are looking 5 to 20 rows, it should `df[5:20,] - df[21,][col(df[5:20,])]`

Comment: Would help to mention your point in the original question, @orangeman51